# view with clause for only one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a view with 3 columns, the first two there are no problems because they are simple sums with groupings by date...for the third I need to add only some values ​​from the initial table, how can i solve? use two where? or two condition for clause? . For example:

```
T1
id||amount||cod_pay||reg_date
1 ||10.00 ||SDD    || 2019-08
2 ||5.00  ||BON    || 2019-08
3 ||15.00 ||SDD    || 2019-07
4 ||10.00 ||BOL    || 2019-06
5 ||40.00 ||SDD    || 2019-06
6 ||110.00||BON    || 2019-06

VIEW
reg_date||month_amount||sdd_month_amount
2019-08 ||15.00       ||10.00           
2019-07 ||15.00       ||15.00           
2019-06 ||160.00      ||40.00
```

I don't know if it's clear, I hope so.
Thanks for the support.

Comment: some values you mention is that anything form amount??

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select reg_date, sum(amount) as month_amount,
       sum(case when cod_pay = 'SDD' then amount end) as sdd_amount
from t
group by reg_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d1abf65204bd248895de8ad74e50163) is a db<>fiddle, illustrating that it works.

Comment: this query actually provides
"2019-06" "160" \N
"2019-07" "15" "15"
"2019-08" "15" "10"

Comment: @anikislamShojib . . . It works fine when I run it.